# Transpose duplicate rows to columns SQL (no pivot command)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates, transpose

I am trying to transpose rows to columns because they have duplicates depending on products ordered on an orderId.

Currently it looks like this

| OrderID | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | Tent1 |
| 501 | accessory |

I would like to have it look like this

| OrderID | ProductName | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 501 | Tent1 | Accessory |

```sql
Select 
  
  order_created_date_time,
  bc_order.order_id, 
  product_name,
  sku, quantity,
  order_status
  
  
From BC.bc_order

Left join 
  
  BC.bc_order_line_items
  
on bc_order_line_items.order_id = bc_order.order_id


Left join
  
  BC.bc_product
  
on bc_product.product_id = bc_order_line_items.product_id

where order_status = 'Awaiting Fulfillment'
or 
order_status like 'partial%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
execute immediate format('''
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by OrderID) pos 
  from your_table
)
pivot (any_value(ProductName) ProductName for pos in (%s))
''', (
  select (select string_agg('' || num) from unnest(generate_array(1,max_names)) num)
  from (
    select count(ProductName) max_names
    from your_table group by OrderID
    qualify 1 =  row_number() over(order by max_names desc)
)))
```

with output like below

[image]